acmart with nonacm does not show date
I am using:
\documentclass[nonacm,natbib=false]{acmart}
\date{\today}

The top matter now includes the title and my name but no date. How can I get the date?

Without specifying a format under acmart, the default manuscript is assumed (that is, format=manuscript). Under that format, the date is completely ignored in the title (set by \@mkauthors - the author setting as part of \maketitle). If you want it added, you can add it after the author (list) printing using a patch:
\makeatletter
% format=manuscript results in setting authors via \@mkauthors@i
\patchcmd{\@mkauthors@i}% <cmd>
  {\@typeset@author@line\par}% <search>
  {\@typeset@author@line\par\noindent\@date\par}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

With this active,
\title{A title}
\author{An author}
\date{\today}

% ...

\makeatitle

will now produce:


The acmart class never uses \date. The command is defined by the LaTeX kernel
% latex.ltx, line 15586:
\DeclareRobustCommand*\date[1]{\gdef\@date{#1}}

but \@date never appears in acmart.cls; it does in amsart.cls that's loaded by acmart, but neither its \@setdate command appears.
If you want that the date appears somewhere, you can use \thanks.
\documentclass[nonacm,natbib=false]{acmart}

\author{me}
\title{Title}

\thanks{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}


(The image has been shortened, the date appears at the foot.)
